# Ticker symbols differences between Yahoo Finance and BestInvest

Tags: stocks, etf, yahoo-finance

I expected Yahoo to have all existing tickers, yet when I grab the list of ETF tickers available through [BestInvest](http://www.bestinvest.co.uk/media/723681/etf-available-select.pdf),  I see tickers like "EUN iShares STOXX Europe 50 UCITS ETF" however Yahoo shows this as being EUN.L.

Some tickers like "CMFP ETFX DJ-UBS All Commodities Forward 3 Month Fund" show up in Yahoo as something completely different in [Yahoo](http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=CMFP&ql=1).

And others like "FLEG UBS BBG SPGSCI Constant Maturity Composite Index 
Hgd GBP" don't show up even as being valid.

What's going on? I thought tickers would have a universal name and sites like Yahoo would provide me information for all.

Answer (score 1):

BestInvest is a UK site looking at that URL, base on the "co.uk" ending.

Yahoo! Finance that you use is a US-based site unless you add something else to the URL. [UK & Ireland Yahoo! Finance](https://uk.finance.yahoo.com/) is different from where you were as there is something to be said for where are you looking.

If I was looking for a quarter dollar there are Canadian and American coins that meet this so there is something to be said for a higher level of categorization being done. "EUN.L" would likely denote the "London" exchange as tickers are exchange-specific you do realize, right?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what site you're looking on and what exchange they're pulling the data from. Even though funds and stocks are called the same thing, they have different ticker symbols in each country's exchange or could be traded as pink sheet stocks in the US. If a company or fund is based in another country (like Canada or the UK) they probably also trade on that country's exchange (Toronto or London) under a different symbol. This can cause a lot of confusion when researching these tickers.